# Make return that directory is not recognized as an internal or external command on windows

Tags: windows, bash, make, git-bash

I have project that use make that usually run on GNU/Linux and now I've try to run it on windows and got error (from git bash):

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I've removed the dot before node_modules and then I got error that node_modules is not recognized. node_modules was created in my directory when I've run npm install.

I've tried both MinGW and GNUWin version of make both return same error, the project was working last time I run it on windows about an year ago.

Here is my makefile that fail:

```
VERSION=1.16.1
SED=sed
CD=cd
NPM=npm
CP=cp
RM=rm
CAT=cat
DATE=`date -uR`
GIT=git
BRANCH=`git branch | grep '^*' | sed 's/* //'`
ESLINT=node_modules/.bin/eslint
UGLIFY=node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
JSONLINT=node_modules/.bin/jsonlint
JEST=node_modules/.bin/jest
CSSNANO=./node_modules/.bin/cssnano
SPEC_CHECKSUM=`md5sum __tests__/terminalSpec.js | cut -d' ' -f 1`
COMMIT=`git log -n 1 | grep commit | sed 's/commit //'`
URL=`git config --get remote.origin.url`
skip_re="[xfi]it\\(|[fdx]describe\\("

.PHONY: coverage test coveralls lint.src eslint skipped_tests jsonlint publish lint

ALL: Makefile .$(VERSION) terminal.jquery.json bower.json package.json js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js js/jquery.terminal.js js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js js/jquery.terminal.min.js css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.css css/jquery.terminal.min.css css/jquery.terminal.css README.md import.html js/terminal.widget.js www/Makefile

foo:
    echo `pwd`

bower.json: templates/bower.in .$(VERSION)
    $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" templates/bower.in > bower.json

package.json: templates/package.in .$(VERSION)
    $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" templates/package.in > package.json

js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js: js/jquery.terminal-src.js .$(VERSION)
    $(GIT) branch | grep '* devel' > /dev/null && $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/DEV/g" -e "s/{{DATE}}/$(DATE)/g" js/jquery.terminal-src.js > js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js || $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" -e "s/{{DATE}}/$(DATE)/g" js/jquery.terminal-src.js > js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js

js/jquery.terminal.js: js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js
    $(CP) js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js js/jquery.terminal.js

js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js: js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js
    $(UGLIFY) -o js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js --comments --mangle -- js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js

js/jquery.terminal.min.js: js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js
    $(CP) js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js js/jquery.terminal.min.js

css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css: css/jquery.terminal-src.css .$(VERSION)
    $(GIT) branch | grep '* devel' > /dev/null && $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/DEV/g" -e "s/{{DATE}}/$(DATE)/g" css/jquery.terminal-src.css > css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css || $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" -e "s/{{DATE}}/$(DATE)/g" css/jquery.terminal-src.css > css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css

css/jquery.terminal.css: css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css .$(VERSION)
    $(CP) css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css css/jquery.terminal.css

css/jquery.terminal.min.css: css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.css
    $(CP) css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.css css/jquery.terminal.min.css

css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.css: css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css
    $(CSSNANO) css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).css css/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.css --no-discardUnused --safe

README.md: templates/README.in .$(VERSION)
    $(GIT) branch | grep '* devel' > /dev/null && $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/DEV/g" -e \
    "s/{{BRANCH}}/$(BRANCH)/g" -e "s/{{CHECKSUM}}/$(SPEC_CHECKSUM)/" \
    -e "s/{{COMMIT}}/$(COMMIT)/g" < templates/README.in > README.md || $(SED) -e \
    "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" -e "s/{{BRANCH}}/$(BRANCH)/g" -e \
    "s/{{CHECKSUM}}/$(SPEC_CHECKSUM)/" -e "s/{{COMMIT}}/$(COMMIT)/g" < templates/README.in > README.md

.$(VERSION): Makefile
    touch .$(VERSION)

Makefile: templates/Makefile.in
    $(SED) -e "s/{{VER""SION}}/"$(VERSION)"/" templates/Makefile.in > Makefile

import.html: templates/import.in
    $(SED) -e "s/{{BRANCH}}/$(BRANCH)/g" templates/import.in > import.html

js/terminal.widget.js: js/terminal.widget.in
    $(GIT) branch | grep '* devel' > /dev/null || $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" js/terminal.widget.in > js/terminal.widget.js

terminal.jquery.json: manifest .$(VERSION)
    $(SED) -e "s/{{VER}}/$(VERSION)/g" manifest > terminal.jquery.json

www/Makefile: $(wildcard www/Makefile.in) Makefile .$(VERSION)
    @test "$(BRANCH)" = "master" -a -d www && $(SED) -e "s/{{VER""SION}}/$(VERSION)/g" www/Makefile.in > www/Makefile || true

test:
    $(JEST) --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=js/{unix_formatting,jquery.terminal-src}.js

coveralls:
    $(CAT) ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js

lint.src:
    $(ESLINT) js/jquery.terminal-src.js

eslint:
    $(ESLINT) js/jquery.terminal-src.js
    $(ESLINT) js/dterm.js
    $(ESLINT) js/xml_formatting.js
    $(ESLINT) js/unix_formatting.js
    $(ESLINT) js/prims.js
    $(ESLINT) js/less.js

skipped_tests:
    @! grep -E $(skip_re) __tests__/terminalSpec.js

jsonlint: package.json bower.json
    $(JSONLINT) package.json > /dev/null
    $(JSONLINT) bower.json > /dev/null

publish:
    $(GIT) clone $(URL) --depth 1 npm
    $(CD) npm && $(NPM) publish
    $(RM) -rf npm

lint: eslint jsonlint
```

make foo return correct directory.

the problem is this rule:

```
UGLIFY=./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs

js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js: js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js
    $(UGLIFY) -o js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).min.js --comments --mangle -- js/jquery.terminal-$(VERSION).js
```

but when I run the command from same directory in gitbash it was run successful, I've also tried to run export PATH=.:$PATH before run make and got the same error.

I've also tried to change line ending of Makefile from unix to windows but that also didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was slash vs backslash. So solution is to use different path for windows and linux:

```
ifdef SYSTEMROOT
  UGLIFY=.\node_modules\.bin\uglifyjs
  JSONLINT=.\node_modules\.bin\jsonlint
  JEST=.\node_modules\.bin\jest
  CSSNANO=.\node_modules\.bin\cssnano
  ESLINT=.\node_modules\.bin\eslint
else
  UGLIFY=./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
  JSONLINT=./node_modules/.bin/jsonlint
  JEST=./node_modules/.bin/jest
  CSSNANO=./node_modules/.bin/cssnano
  ESLINT=./node_modules/.bin/eslint
endif
```